# Change color of input field in datepicker [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker

Hi Im using showDatePicker and what I want to do is to have a different color for my input number field for date picker. Here is what I mean:

[image]

As you can see the color is white and its not visible unless you highlight it, how can I change this text to Colors.red. Thanks in advance :D

Current DatePicker:

```
 TextSpan(
                          text:
                              ' - ${DateFormat.yMMMd($LocalizationService.$instance(this).currentLocale.languageCode).format(widget.localCartModel.value!.cartModel.deliveryDate!)}   ',
                          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                          children: [
                            TextSpan(
                              text: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.change,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                color: bloc.customColors[AppCustomColors.SEARCH_AND_FOOTER_BACKGROUND]!,
                              ),
                              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                ..onTap = () => { showDatePicker(
                                          // Disables certain dates
                                          selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime val) {
                                            String sanitized = sanitizeDateTime(val);
                                            return availableDates.contains(sanitized);
                                          },
                                          builder: (context, child) {
                                            return Theme(
                                              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                                                dialogTheme: DialogTheme(
                                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                                        20.0), // this is the border radius of the picker
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                                                  primary: Colors.blue,
                                                  onSurface: Colors.black,
                                                  error: Colors.red,
                                                ),
                                                textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
                                                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      fontSize: 12,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                    ),
                                                    primary: Colors.white,
                                                    backgroundColor:
                                                        Colors.blue,
                                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              child: child!,
                                            );
                                          },
```

Comment: Can you include your current picker?

Comment: Sorry, failed to reproduce the error,

Answer (score 0):

This text color does not depend on the `DatePicker`, it is coming from the `style` set to the `TextField` that has the call of the method `showDatePicker()`.

Just set the `color` inside the `style` property in the `TextField` to whatever color you want.

Comment: The thing is I have invoke the showDatePicker via onTap, so how can I wrap this function in Theme so i can assign it a new textTheme

Comment: What is the widget you are invoking the method from?

Comment: TextSpan -> recognizer where I use TapGestureRecognizer

Comment: Could you please update the question and include the full code for this part?

Comment: Have you tried to add the color to this one?

`style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),`

Comment: yeah just added it, did not resolve the issue

Comment: If you still facing the issue, then please add a minimal reproduceable snippet for the issue cause I'm not able to run your snippet easily.